# Entity Framework 6 too many joins

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var query = from a in c.ArticleSet
            where a.GlobalAccess == false && 
                  a.Published == true && 
                  a.MagazineSet.IsPublished == true && 
                  a.MagazineSet.Press_Id == pressId && 
                  a.Tests.Id==a.Id && 
                  a.Tests.IsDeleted == false && 
                  a.Tests.IsPublished == true
            orderby a.Id descending
            select a.Id;
```

It tranforms to SQL like this:

```
ADO.NET:Execute Reader "SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter3].[Id1] AS [Id]
    FROM   (SELECT [Filter2].[Id1], [Filter2].[Magazine_Id1], [Filter2].[Press_Id1], [Filter2].[Press_Id2], [Filter2].[Press_Id3]
        FROM    (SELECT [Filter1].[Id1], [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1], [Extent5].[Press_Id] AS [Press_Id1], [Extent6].[Press_Id] AS [Press_Id2], [Extent7].[Press_Id] AS [Press_Id3]
            FROM       (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[Magazine_Id] AS [Magazine_Id1]
                FROM   [dbo].[ArticleSet] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]) AND ([Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id])
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Magazine_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
                WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[GlobalAccess]) AND (1 = [Extent1].[Published]) AND (1 = [Extent3].[IsPublished]) ) AS [Filter1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent4].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent5] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent5].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent6] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent6].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent7] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent7].[Id]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent8] ON [Filter1].[Id1] = [Extent8].[Id]
            WHERE 0 = [Extent8].[IsDeleted] ) AS [Filter2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent9] ON [Filter2].[Id1] = [Extent9].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent10] ON [Filter2].[Id1] = [Extent10].[Id]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent10].[IsPublished] ) AS [Filter3]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent11] ON [Filter3].[Id1] = [Extent11].[Id]
    WHERE (([Filter3].[Press_Id1] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Filter3].[Press_Id2] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Filter3].[Press_Id3] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] DESC"
```

The command text

```
"SELECT [Project1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Filter3].[Id1] AS [Id]
    FROM   (SELECT [Filter2].[Id1], [Filter2].[Magazine_Id1], [Filter2].[Press_Id1], [Filter2].[Press_Id2], [Filter2].[Press_Id3]
        FROM    (SELECT [Filter1].[Id1], [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1], [Extent5].[Press_Id] AS [Press_Id1], [Extent6].[Press_Id] AS [Press_Id2], [Extent7].[Press_Id] AS [Press_Id3]
            FROM       (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[Magazine_Id] AS [Magazine_Id1]
                FROM   [dbo].[ArticleSet] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]) AND ([Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id])
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Magazine_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
                WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[GlobalAccess]) AND (1 = [Extent1].[Published]) AND (1 = [Extent3].[IsPublished]) ) AS [Filter1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent4].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent5] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent5].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent6] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent6].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MagazineSet] AS [Extent7] ON [Filter1].[Magazine_Id1] = [Extent7].[Id]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent8] ON [Filter1].[Id1] = [Extent8].[Id]
            WHERE 0 = [Extent8].[IsDeleted] ) AS [Filter2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent9] ON [Filter2].[Id1] = [Extent9].[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent10] ON [Filter2].[Id1] = [Extent10].[Id]
        WHERE 1 = [Extent10].[IsPublished] ) AS [Filter3]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tests] AS [Extent11] ON [Filter3].[Id1] = [Extent11].[Id]
    WHERE (([Filter3].[Press_Id1] = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT ([Filter3].[Press_Id2] IS NULL OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL))) OR (([Filter3].[Press_Id3] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] DESC
```

I think 3 join is enough in this example.
Why does Entity framework create such huge query?

Comment: What query do you think should be produced?

Comment: In this situations I prefer to write joins manually - it produces better sql-code

Answer (score 0):

Your linq query is fine, other than the fact that it references a lot of tables at once. If this is really what you want, there there is nothing to be afraid of. It's only not "super efficient" because you are referencing 3 tables at once.

Just remember that the sql query that EF produces is machine-created. It's not always the best, but it should alway be perfectly valid. I'm not sure why it chose this form over another, but if it works, why worry?

I always suggest that people limit their queries to only the referencing tables they need. As the system grows, the processing time will increase as well, and with this many table joins, it might start to get more noticeable.